# MongoDB - Issue Deleting Documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Sorry - I'm new with Mongo....

I'm using it as storage for logs in my web application.  I'd like to run a rake task periodically to delete my scripted automatic site checks.

I can successfully pull the documents with the params of interest:

```
coll.find("params.from" => "sitecheck").to_a.count
   => 5
```

However, they won't drop!

```
coll.remove("params.from" => "sitecheck")
   => true 
coll.find("params.from" => "sitecheck").to_a.count
   => 5
```

I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid.... help would be apprecaited though :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.... I'm using a capped collection.  Can't remove from it...

Comment: Removing documents from a capped collection is one of the [Usage Restrictions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-UsageandRestrictions).  The documents automatically age out of the collection based on insertion order ([First In, First Out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)).

Comment: I have an automated site checker hit the site every 30 mintues.  I was hoping to delete these occasionally to keep the logs from clogging up. Barring the ability to delete these, is there any way to prevent MongoDB from saving these objects?  Or an "after save callback" to get rid of them?

Comment: A capped collection will keep your data within a specified byte size (and optionally [max documents](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections#CappedCollections-Options)) which is an automatic strategy to manage data. There is also a new [TTL (Time-To-Live) collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) coming in MongoDB 2.2. If you want to specifically control the deletion timing for data you should use a normal (non-capped) collection. Capped collections are frequently used for [logging](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging).